# Questions about this JS script

Tags: javascript

I found this JS script on the internet but I am unsure on how to adjust this one from the index.php file.

So this script has a section which holds all the default values. The file is a .js file:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend({

        smoothScroll: function() {

            // Scroll Variables (tweakable)
            var defaultOptions = {

                // Scrolling Core
                frameRate        : 150, // [Hz]
                animationTime    : 700, // [px]
                stepSize         : 80, // [px]

                // Pulse (less tweakable)
                // ratio of "tail" to "acceleration"
                pulseAlgorithm   : true,
                pulseScale       : 8,
                pulseNormalize   : 1,

                // Acceleration
                accelerationDelta : 20,  // 20
                accelerationMax   : 1,   // 1

                // Keyboard Settings
                keyboardSupport   : true,  // option
                arrowScroll       : 50,     // [px]

                // Other
                touchpadSupport   : true,
                fixedBackground   : true,
                excluded          : ""
            };

            // rest of script
```

I want to adjust these settings from the frontpage, *the index.php*, using JavaScript because I have seen this before, I just don't know how to do it.

So for a example:

index.php

```
<script>
    smoothScroll {
        frameRate => 120
        animationTime => 500
        stepSize => 50
    }
</script>
```

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: You haven't told us which plugin this is but usually you would pass an object with your custom settings when you initialise the plugin: `$.smoothScroll({ frameRate: 500; animationTime: 100 });`. The plugins documentation will tell you how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object is made like this:

```
var obj = {
    key: "value" // if value is a string
    key1: 123    // if value is a number
    // just to show two examples
};
```

So, to adapt this to your situation, where you have to pass an object to a function, do something like

```
$.smoothScroll({
    frameRate: 120,
    animationTime: 500,
    stepSize: 50
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function is $.smoothScroll, because it's a jQuery plugin. Function arguments have to be put inside (). Objects in Javascript use `:` between the key and value, not `=>`, and they need `,` between the properties.

So it should be:

```
$.smoothScroll({
    frameRate: 120,
    animationTime: 500,
    stepSize: 50
});
```

Also, since this is a jQuery plugin, you need to load jQuery first if the page isn't already doing so.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```